# create undirectional adjacency matrix in python

Tags: python

I have a adjacency list which I want to convert to matrix, My data looks something like this

```
User_Name    M_User     Total
user 1       user 2      1
user 1       user 3      1
user 1       user 3      1
user 1       user 7      1
user 3       user 2      1
user 2       user 7      1
```

The end result should look like this

```
            user 1   user 2   user 3   user 7 

user 1         0         1        1       1
user 2         1         0        1       1
user 3         1         1        0       0
user 7         1         1        0       0
```

an undirectional matrix, however I'm getting a directional matrix

```
            user 1   user 2  user 3  user 7 
user 1         0       1       1        1
user 2         0       0       0        1
user 3         0       1       0        0
user 7         0       0       0        0
```

how do I get an undirectional matrix, this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/file.csv")
df = df.drop_duplicates()

df = pd.crosstab(df.User_Name, df.M_User)
idx = df.columns.union(df.index)
df = df.reindex(index = idx, columns=idx, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Is it *that* hard to mark two values at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the matrix is square, just take the union of the original matrix and its transposed copy:

```
df.T|df
#        user 1  user 2  user 3  user 7
#user 1       0       1       1       1
#user 2       1       0       1       1
#user 3       1       1       0       0
#user 7       1       1       0       0
```